# How to restaure a dropped package in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i've dropped an important package of my project (involuntarily) i now i want to restaure it. Please can you help me ?

Here's what i tried to do :

> ```
> RESTAURE PACKAGE package_name;
> ```

I work with oracle sql developer

Comment: Check your sql history in the worksheet, you might get lucky. Otherwise now you know why we advocate source control for source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `restore package` command.  If you've dropped the package, you may need to get it back from your source control system.

If you're reasonably lucky, you may be able to run a flashback query to see the source.  Assuming you dropped it less than 20 minutes ago (otherwise adjust the timestamp you're flashing back to)

```
select type, line, text
  from all_source as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '20' minute
 where owner = <<schema owner>>
   and name = <<name of package>>
   and type in ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY')
 order by type, line;
```

Oracle retains the `undo` data necessary to do a flashback query for a limited period of time.  If it has been too long since you dropped the package, Oracle may well not be able to show you what the code looks like.

Comment: owner = the user connected ?

Comment: @Dev1996 - The owner of the object.  Most of the time, if you're connected to the database as the user `FOO`, you'd be creating objects in the `FOO` schema so `FOO` would be the owner.  You could (depending on permissions) be connecting as `FOO` and creating objects in the `BAR` schema but that would be unusual.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Cave